# Auto zero-padding an array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Let `L` be a list of, say, 55 items :

```
L=range(55)
for i in range(6):
 print L[10*i:10*(i+1)]
```

The printed list will have 10 items for i = 0, 1, 2, 3 , 4,  but for i = 5, it will have 5 items only.

Is there a quick method for auto zero-padding L[50:60] so that it is 10 items-long ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> L = range(55)
>>> for i in range(6):
...     print (L[10*i:10*(i+1)] + [0]*10)[:10]
...
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
[30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]
[40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
[50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: `pprint` will do better?

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil, Is it related to the question?

Comment: Nope, just asking if it would print the way i think it will? Nvm, I am trying it out.

Answer (score 7):

Using `NumPy`:

```
>>> a = np.arange(55)
>>> a.resize(60)
>>> a.reshape(6, 10)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Comment: I believe you could combine the `resize` and `reshape` steps and just do `a.resize(6, 10)`.  Also, since OP seems interested in printing, perhaps a better solution would be `np.resize(a, (6, 10))` which returns a resized _copy_ instead of modifying the original array.

Comment: @askewchan But [`np.resize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html#numpy.ndarray.resize) won't pad 0 at the end of the array.

Comment: You're right, it repeats the array :P  When testing, I saw that the shape matched and didn't look for the zeros.  What a strange inconsistency; it would really be nice if both offered a `fill=` keyword.

Answer (score 3):

This might look like wizardry, also please note that this create a `tuple` and not a list.

```
from itertools import izip_longest

L = range(55)
list_size = 10
padded = list(izip_longest(*[iter(L)] * list_size, fillvalue=0))
for l in padded:
    print l
```

For an explanation about the `zip` + `iter` trick see the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: in python 3.x, the function name is zip_longest

Answer (score 2):

You can also build the intelligence into your objects.  I have left out corner cases; this just illustrates the point.

```
class ZeroList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index >= len(self):c
            return 0
        else: return super(ZeroList,self).__getitem__(index)

    def __getslice__(self,i,j):
        numzeros = j-len(self)
        if numzeros <= 0:
            return super(ZeroList,self).__getslice__(i,j)
        return super(ZeroList,self).__getslice__(i,len(self)) + [0]*numzeros

>>> l = ZeroList(range(55))
>>> l[40:50]
[40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
>>> l[50:60]
[50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: A bit overkill, but cool :)  Be careful with your indentations.  There should be an additional 4 spaces to indent the code on [SO], which may interfere with tab-indentation.